# LEGO Master Builder Academy instructions

Tags: instructions, discontinued

My kids picked up a few LEGO sets from the [Master Builder Academy](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/LEGO_Master_Builder_Academy) series recently that do not come with instructions in the packaging. According to the support team at LEGO.com this series was discontinued in 2011 and no electronic copies of the instructions were ever produced by the company. We are looking for instructions for [20201](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/20201_Microbuild_Designer), [20204](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/20204_Creature_Designer), and [20205](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/20205_Auto_Designer).

I have googled quite a bit and searched several LEGO fan sites but have been unable to find any scans or other digital copies of the instructions for any of these sets.

Does anyone have or know where to find these? Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the instruction booklets on BrickLink. They only costs a few dollars. They are not just about instructions. They include a whole curriculum for systematically learning advanced building techniques and building concepts with lots of information, seed ideas, alternate builds, etc. Here are the listings for the for LEGO Master Builder Academy booklets: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=I&catString=764